# Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyAllForm with attachments not working outlook.live.com and outlook api giving internal server error

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Using office.js outlook add-ins, displayReplyAllForm with attachments is opening reply form without attachments in [outlook.live.com](https://outlook.live.com), but in [outlook.office.com](https://outlook.office.com) its working perfect.

Any workaround for this.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyAllForm(
                    {
                        'htmlBody': template,
                        'attachments': attachments
                    });
```

thanks,
Nadeer

[image]

and response is

[image]

Comment: I also have the same problem move to the discussion here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686499/office-add-in-outlook-api-attach-document-using-displaynewmessageform-method-iss)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this snippet of code, but could not reproduce a problem:

```
    Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyAllForm(
{
  'htmlBody' : 'hi',
  'attachments' :
  [
    {
      'type' : Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentType.File,
      'name' : 'squirrel.png',
      'url' : 'http://i.imgur.com/sRgTlGR.jpg'
    }
  ]
});
```

does this not work for you?

Comment: So I tested this code, on outlook.live.com. This works if you do NOT have a pop-up blocker. However, if you do have a pop-up blocker, then results are mixed. On Edge if you allow the pop-up afterward, then it will open the new item, but not attach the image. On Chrome, the pop-up blocker will not allow the reply form at all. Can you disable your pop-up blocker and see if the code works?

Comment: @TimWan it's not working for outlook.live.com. I am using MinVersion="1.2"  but still not working. Its opening reply box with text but no attachments in it.

Comment: Can we get more details? Did you test AndrewS's snippet? I was assuming this was in OWA... but is this on Desktop Outlook? If OWA, what browser and what version are you on? If this is Desktop Outlook, also what version are you on? (File->Office Account->About Outlook), or are you on another client? If you are using your own snippet of code, what is the URL of the attachment that you are trying to attach (if you can provide that)

Comment: Hi ...i am doing the same approach as suggested by AndrewS it is not working...it is giving 500 internal server error from api..https://outlook.live.com/owa/service.svc?action=CreateAttachmentFromUri&EP=1&ID=-98&AC=1...please suggest