# Office Add-in Outlook API attach document using displayNewMessageForm method issue

Tags: api, outlook-addin, add-in, office-js, outlook-restapi

I'm working on office Add-in for Outlook. Need to open a new message with a pre-defined attachment.

Trying to get an attachment from the current item (message) as below:

```
 Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments
```

Here is an output (i get attachment type, id, size and so on):

[image]

Then I'm trying to attach this file to a new message in Outlook via add-in outlook API, here is an example from [Office Developer](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox.md) that I use to attach the file I just get from the other email (like 'forward' functionality):

```
  Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm(
  {
    toRecipients: Office.context.mailbox.item.to, // Copy the To line from current item
    ccRecipients: ['sam@contoso.com'],
    subject: 'Outlook add-ins are cool!',
    htmlBody: 'Hello <b>World</b>!<br/><img src="cid:image.png"></i>',
    attachments: [
      {
        type: 'file',
        name: 'image.png',
        url: 'http://contoso.com/image.png',
        isInline: true
      }
    ]
  });
```

**Here is an issue**: I'm getting an exception 'Value doesn't fall within the expected range'. Parameter name: Attachments.

[image]

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: The screenshot you have provided displays wrong parameters set, according to documentation. Attachment with EWS `ItemId` can be only type '`item`' and screenshot shows the attachment as '`file`'. The code on screenshot doesn't looks right as `attachment` object has property `itemId` and there is no `id` in this object. I suggest you post the code you are actually using, not example from the doc.

Comment: actually, I tried different scenario and also try to add as an item, but error the same
http://prntscr.com/jr6hsd

Comment: The last screenshot of your code has mistakes as well. Please read [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox) careful. 1. `isInline` property should not be set for `type` with value '`item`'. 2. When `type` set to '`item`' you have to have `itemId` property set; your code by some reason set `id`.

Comment: oh, yes you are right I fixed the options, but a new window open without attachment. I think Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments[0].id  is not itemId, because ItemId is a string up to 100 characters(by documentation) but my Id  has length 160. Do you have advice how to get or convert from attachment id to ews id? http://prntscr.com/jr92w6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation on [`displayNewMessageForm`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox) there are currently two attachment types are supported. To attach file to the item the attachment object should looks like ...

```
{
    type: 'file',
    name: 'image.png',
    url: 'http://contoso.com/image.png',
    isInline: true
}
```

To attach the item from existing message the object should looks ...

```
{
    type: 'item',
    name: 'image.png',
    itemId: 'ews_item_id_goes_here'
}
```

Comment: thanks, that works if I use item.itemId as attachments, but when I use Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments[0].id I have a new message without an attachment, I think the problem with id, do you have an idea how to get correct ews id ?

Comment: To convert REST formatted `itemId` to EWS use the function [Office.context.mailbox.convertToEwsId](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox)

Comment: yes, I also tried this and it's not working. Actually, after this method, nothing happens -  the id is the same.
I tried using  SOAP request on the server (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-GetAttachments), and it's working, but the main goal adds to attach for a new message.

Comment: @SamLewis My bad, the [AttachmentDetails](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/simple-types?product=outlook) when you iterate through `Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments` already should have `id` as Exchange attachment ID, which is I assume the same as EWS Id. Why this Id doesn't work with `attachment` object I am not sure. Would you mind to post another question just regarding Ids?

Comment: @SamLewis Obviously, you may use [makeEwsRequestAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook) and retrieve the attachments Ids directly from Exchange with XML request similar to [Get an attachment from an email by using EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange#get-an-attachment-from-an-email-by-using-ews), but it doesn't explain why you cannot use Ids from attachments list.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I've created a separate request for attachment ID.